# Excel VB This Active Worksheet

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I'm sure this is really easy but I can't find any info on it.

I've got a Excel macro which has things like:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data 21 Oct 12 11-05").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data21 Oct 12 11-05").Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
    :=Range("W1:W23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data 21 Oct 12 11-05").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:BZ23")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

What I want to do is make this a global macro but the file name is hard coded in the macro. How can I change the code so it references "this" currently open file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I worked out you need to change it from:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data 21 Oct 12 11-05").Sort.
```

to:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
```

Credit to [this SO item on creating a button in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745017/excel-2007-need-help-creating-a-button-which-takes-the-contents-of-active-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

`ActiveWorkbook` does reference the current open and active file.

If by *file name* you refer to the fact that the sheet name is hard coded, you can make the macro work with the active **sheet** by replacing `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data 21 Oct 12 11-05")` with `ActiveSheet`.